# Magento 2.3: InvalidAgumentException: Composer could not find the config file

Tags: magento2.3, composer, exception, core, xdebug

I have a problem with Magento, I use X-debug for trying to debug Magento and I have the following Exception:

> **Exception Has ocurred.**   InvalidArgumentException: Composer could not find the config file:
>   /var/www/site/magento/var/composer_home/composer.json   To initialize
>   a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
>   https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

So yeah it's right in magento/var there is no composer.json, BUT this is a Magento core folder and included in .gitignore given by Magento to one of this famous "don't touch" folder from Magento.

This exception is thrown by the function createComposer in vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php

Someone had similar error ? If yes how did you deal with it ?

PS: in case of minus please let me know why so then I can upgrade this post

Answer (score 2):

Ok since commenting is not enabled. I kept digging with no answers. Then I thought I would create the composer.json file in var/composer_home. The contents of said file was:

```
{}
```

Now I am able to execute bin/magento commands without the exception. I'm certain there is another issue, but unless someone can find it this is the workaround I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a solution but today I just saw this same error messaging when performing any bin/magento command.

Comment: If you don't have solution or proper answer than just don't put as an answer.